# How to call UIButton action method without tapping on button?

Tags: ios, swift

// **Funtion Method**

```
func TappedButtonCallFunction()
{
  btnSaveFilterWorkLog(UIButton.init())
}
```

// **Button Action**

```
@IBAction func btnSaveFilterWorkLog(_ sender: UIButton) {

    print("Button Tapped")
}
```

//  Button Tapped

Comment: Put your Funtion Method in view did load.

Comment: where you need to call the `TappedButtonCallFunction`, I mean in which scenario

Comment: Just call  yourButton.sendActions(for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside) from your viewDidLoad

Comment: Better you create function and call same function from the action of button, and based upon requirement you can call this method !!!

Comment: Please search for already answered questions first.

Answer (score 2):

The proper way is to use [sendAction](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol/1618211-sendactions) method from the UIControl class.

> You call this method when you want the control to perform the actions associated with the specified events.

In our case:

```
button.sendActions(for: .touchUpOutside)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put **?** in function declaration behind **uibutton** object. Now you can pass nil value in argument but make sure you are not using sender anywhere
And do not worry your button tap event will not effected it will work same

//Calling

```
  btnSaveFilterWorkLog(nil)
```

// Button Action

```
@IBAction func btnSaveFilterWorkLog(_ sender: UIButton?) {

    print("Button Tapped")
}
```

Comment: Or just omit it altogether.

Answer (score 1):

also you can create programmatically method

for example:

`button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)`

and method selector:

```
@objc
func buttonAction() {
   print("some")
}
```

don't forget to put `@objc`

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit

class ActionSheetViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var closeButton: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
      
        closeButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(dismissActionSheet), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    @objc func dismissActionSheet() {
        // some code goes here ie:
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Above works perfectly in Swift5.